# C# I Iterate throught a Queue of Tasks and get null, why is that so?

Tags: c#, loops, queue, task

**Hello stackoverflow!**

I need to handle for example two Tasks in a While Loop,
one of them adds an string to his list and the other one reads the list,
everyone of them is getting registered in an Queue (B= Custom Class with Key and Task in it)

yesterday I did an example of this but i received an odd problem, some of my Tasks were "null" and im not sure why?! The funny part is, its the ~180 Task not one of the first..

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static HandlerMessages m;
    static int i = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HandlerQueue.Run();
        m = new HandlerMessages();
        Console.WriteLine("fe");
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                m.Add((i++).ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                m.Read((i++).ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public Task task;
    public string key;
}

public class HandlerMessages
{
    List<string> ll = new List<string>();
    public void Add(string str)
    {
        var action = new Action(() => { ll.Add($"{str}"); });
        var task = new Task(action);
        var b = new B();
        b.key = "Add: " + str;
        b.task = task;
        HandlerQueue.AddTo(b);
    }

    public void Read(string str)
    {
        var action = new Action(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in ll)
            {
            }
        });
        var task = new Task(action);
        var b = new B();
        b.key = "Read: " + str;
        b.task = task;
        HandlerQueue.AddTo(b);
    }
}

public class HandlerQueue
{
    public static Queue<B> queue = new Queue<B>();
    public static void AddTo(B o)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(o);
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (queue.Count != 0)
                {
                    var task = queue.Dequeue();
                    if (task != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(task.key);
                        task.task.Start();
                        task.task.Wait();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error-------");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not thread safe by any stretch of the imagination ...

Comment: Thats why i tryed to do it into a Queue, when i try to use lock(object) i get the same error...

Comment: What will happen when Task is null? exception or the Console.WriteLine with no value?

Comment: Yes, no value at all and an Exeption of Nullpointer, but the Problem is that this Task has an number and this number is representing my "test code" and when the number is null than my "test code", too.. https://i.imgur.com/vYuV8wV.png

Comment: The problem with this code is its kind of a mess, there is are loops doing nothing, delegates for no reason. You create tasks with the constructor (which is always bad), also when its already being called in a task, and many uses of shared resources in an unsafe manor. Its hard to know where to start, there are lot of issues.

Comment: Are you just trying to create a multi producer and consumer queue ?

Comment: This is only an "example code" for my real project, sorry tryed to write it fast. Yes i think its similar to his consumer queue.

Comment: I would take a look into channels maybe, or TPL DataFlow, definitely concurrent collections. If you had a more specific question about producers and consumers i think you would get a much more satisfying solution

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public static Queue<B> queue = new Queue<B>();
...
...
var task = queue.Dequeue();
```

to

```
public static ConcurrentQueue<B> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<B>();
...
...
queue.TryDequeue(out B task);
```

According [Queue Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=net-5.0) Thread Safety part

> Thread Safety
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this
> type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be
> thread safe.
>
> To guarantee the thread safety of the Queue, all operations must be
> done through the wrapper returned by the Synchronized(Queue) method.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
> procedure. Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can
> still modify the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an
> exception. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can
> either lock the collection during the entire enumeration or catch the
> exceptions resulting from changes made by other threads.

[ConcurrentQueue Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0)

According [ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue?view=net-5.0)

You need to handle what you want when the result is false

> Remarks ConcurrentQueue handles all synchronization internally. If
> two threads call TryDequeue at precisely the same moment, neither
> operation is blocked. When a conflict is detected between two threads,
> one thread has to try again to retrieve the next element, and the
> synchronization is handled internally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think the solution was the "thread safe"..

I just changed it into:

```
private static object locki = false;
public static void AddTo(B o)
    {
        lock (locki)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(o);
        }
    }


    public static void Run()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (queue.Count != 0)
                {
                    lock (locki)
                    {
                        var task = queue.Dequeue();
                        if (task != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(task.key);
                            task.task.Start();
                            task.task.Wait();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Dont receive **any errors** now :) Thank you guys.